# Language Server Protocol: find all methods

Tags: language-server-protocol

I am exploring LSP to get a feel for what it can do. Most things are pretty obvious, completion, find references, etc. I've been told that LSP will allow me to find all functions/methods in a given language but I've yet to figure out how that might be possible. After much searching and doing some investigations with a few languages in Emacs, I am starting to doubt that it is even possible. Am I missing something? Is it possible with a given LSP instance to find all methods by file, line and column location?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the **workspace symbol** functionality. If you look in the ["vscode-languageserver-protocol](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/tree/master/protocol/src) project, it says:

> /**
>
> - A request to list project-wide symbols matching the query string given
> - by the WorkspaceSymbolParams. The response is
> - of type SymbolInformation[] or a Thenable that
> - resolves to such.
>   */

[LSP Documentation on Workspace](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#workspace_workspaceFolders)

If you're using a client, you'd find the method that calls that. In the project I'm trying to do, using the Brackets.io client, the method is

`client.requestSymbolsForDocument`

for example. If you're writing your own client, then you'd implement the appropriate method. You may get some extra help [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features). For all functions in the current document, then look at **document symbols**.

That's about as I know, I'm also learning.

Good luck.

Sethmo